# php export xml CDATA escaped

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to export xml with `CDATA` tags. I use the following code:

```
$xml_product = $xml_products->addChild('product');
$xml_product->addChild('mychild', htmlentities("<![CDATA[" . $mytext . "]]>"));
```

The problem is that I get `CDATA` tags `<` and `>` escaped with `&lt;` and `&gt;` like following:

```
 <mychild>&lt;![CDATA[My some long long long text]]&gt;</mychild>
```

but I need:

```
<mychild><![CDATA[My some long long long text]]></mychild>
```

If I use `htmlentities()` I get lots of errors like `tag raquo is not defined` etc... though there are no any such tags in my text. Probably `htmlentities()` tries to parse my text inside CDATA and convert it, but I dont want it either.

Any ideas how to fix that? Thank you.

**UPD_1** My function which saves xml to file:

```
public static function saveFormattedXmlFile($simpleXMLElement, $output_file) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML(urldecode($simpleXMLElement->asXML()));
    $dom->save($output_file);

}
```

Comment: try urldecode() instead of htmlentities()

Comment: If you use DOMDocument, you can use createCDATASection which does the work for you. (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

Comment: Is it possible to create a CDATA section when I call an `addChild()` function?

Comment: @Masha Why do you want to use a CDATA section there? Why isn't `addChild('mychild', $mytext);` enough? The data which will be added to the XML node will be the same when it is read again.

Comment: because `$mytext` may contain any user input, including html tags, & symbols and something like '&an;' which is not correctly parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short example of how to add a CData section, note the way it skips into using DOMDocument to add the CData section in. The code builds up a `<product>` element, `$xml_product` has a new element `<mychild>` created in it.  This newNode is then imported into a DOMElement using `dom_import_simplexml`.  It then uses the DOMDocument  `createCDATASection` method to properly create the appropriate bit and adds it back into the node.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Products />');

$xml_product = $xml->addChild('product');
$newNode = $xml_product->addChild('mychild');
$mytext = "<html></html>";
$node = dom_import_simplexml($newNode);
$cdata = $node->ownerDocument->createCDATASection($mytext);
$node->appendChild($cdata);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

This example outputs...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products><product><mychild><![CDATA[<html></html>]]></mychild></product></Products>
```